# How to compare values within one column and make it as conditional statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, transpose

so i have this table:

| DATE | NAME | REFERENCE | ITEM_NUMBER | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03/06/2021 | XYC | SAFGASZXFEW | Z1-100-0006 | 102 |
| 03/06/2021 | XYC | SAFGASZXFEW | Z1-100-0002 | 200 |
| 03/06/2021 | XYC | SAFGASZXFEW | A2-50-0003 | 329 |
| 03/06/2021 | XYC | SAFGASZXFEW | A2-50-0007 | 431 |
| 03/07/2021 | ZBA | DSHDRFBVDRF | RV-100-0001 | 653 |
| 03/07/2021 | ZBA | DSHDRFBVDRF | RV-100-0004 | 222 |
| 03/07/2021 | ZBA | DSHDRFBVDRF | A2-50-0002 | 643 |

and i tried to transpose the item_number table with this query:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ITEM_NUMBER like '%-100-%' THEN CAST(TOTAL AS INT)END) 100_1ST,

SUM(CASE WHEN ITEM_NUMBER like '%-100-%' AND (**ITEM_NUMBER<>ITEM_NUMBER**) THEN CAST(TOTAL AS INT)END) 100_2ND,

SUM(CASE WHEN ITEM_NUMBER like '%-50-%' THEN CAST(TOTAL AS INT)END) 50_1ST,

SUM(CASE WHEN ITEM_NUMBER like '%-50-%' AND (**ITEM_NUMBER<>ITEM_NUMBER**) THEN CAST(TOTAL AS INT)END) 50_2ND,
```

And i get the result:

| DATE | NAME | REFERENCE | 100_1ST | 100_2ND | 50_1ST | 50_2ND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03/06/2021 | XYC | SAFGASZXFEW | 202 | NULL | 760 | NULL |
| 03/07/2021 | ZBA | DSHDRFBVDRF | 875 | NULL | 643 | NULL |

And the result i expected is like this:

| DATE | NAME | REFERENCE | 100_1ST | 100_2ND | 50_1ST | 50_2ND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03/06/2021 | XYC | SAFGASZXFEW | 100 | 200 | 329 | 431 |
| 03/07/2021 | ZBA | DSHDRFBVDRF | 653 | 222 | 643 | NULL |

I know that my query is wrong on the conditional statement on 100_2ND and 50_2ND, i still don't know on how to compare between 2 values within one column for example (Z1-100-000**6** & Z1-100-000**2**) which are has the same '%-100-%' attribute but only distinguished by their last digit number, so i can put the TOTAL values into different columns. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `row_number()`.  It is unclear how you are determining the first and second item, but something like this:

```
SELECT date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ITEM_NUMBER LIKE '%-100-%' AND seqnum = 1 THEN TOTAL END) as 100_1ST,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ITEM_NUMBER LIKE '%-100-%' AND seqnum = 2 THEN TOTAL END) as 100_2ND,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ITEM_NUMBER LIKE '%-50-%' AND seqnum = 1 THEN TOTAL END) as 50_1ST,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ITEM_NUMBER LIKE '%-50-%' AND seqnum = 2 THEN TOTAL END) as 50_2ND
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(item_number, '-', 2), '-', -1)
                                ORDER BY item_number
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM t
     ) t
GROUP BY date;
```

Comment: I tried your query but there's an error 'SUBSTRING_INDEX' is not a recognized built in function name, thank you

Comment: @revadwi . . . Your question is tagged MySQL and this is certainly a MySQL function:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index.

Comment: Yes but i don't know why it is error, thank you for your prev answer anyway i can now classify the items using the DENSE_RANK() which is i never thought before.